# How does jQuery Mobile animate the page when you navigate back?

Tags: jquery-mobile

When you click the browser back button on a site with jQuery Mobile, instead of leaving the page immediately the previous page is animated in. How is this achieved? I thought that their was no way to intercept the browser's back button (I can see why browser makers wouldn't want to allow this). Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the hash URL scheme (no `pushState` plugin enabled):

> Hash changes that occur independently of a click, such as when a user
>   clicks the back button, are handled through the **hashchange event**,
>   which is bound to the window object using Ben Alman's hashchange
>   special event plugin (included in jQuery Mobile). When a hash change
>   occurs (and also when the first page loads), the hashchange event
>   handler will send the location.hash to the $.mobile.changePage()
>   function, which in turn either loads or reveals the referenced page.

*Source: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0-rc.1/docs/pages/page-navmodel.html*

When the `pushState` plugin is enabled the same goes but the `hash` is converted into a normal/readable URL:

> There is an optional feature that converts the longer, hash-based URLs
>   mentioned in the previous section into the full document path which is
>   cleaner and makes the Ajax tracking transparent in the URL structure.
>   This is built as an enhancement on top of the hash-based URL system
>   for Ajax links. Note that despite the name, this feature technically
>   converts hash-based urls by using history.replaceState (not
>   history.pushState) in the current release because this works more
>   reliably across our target platforms. For browsers that do not support
>   history.replaceState, or if this feature is disabled, hash-based URLs
>   will be used instead.

*Source: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0-rc.1/docs/pages/page-navmodel.html*

Also here are the MDN docs for the `hashchange` event: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onhashchange